# unable to use handlebars @first data propriety in meteor

Tags: html, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I am rendering my past handlebars projects into a meteor app but it seems that there are `@data` properties that it doesn't support. Like `@first` which I used to create a reactive slideshow.

```js
var carousel = [
    {
        film:"img_1.jpg",
        desc:"the first"
    },
    {
        film:"img_2.jpg",
        desc:"the second"
    },
    {
        film:"img_3.jpg",
        desc:"the third"
    }
];

Template.hello.helpers({net:carousel});
```

```
<div id="MyCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li id="data-target" data-slide-to="0" 
                             class="active"> </li>
            <li id="data-target" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
            <li id="data-target" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
        </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        {{#each net}}
        <div class="carousel {{@index}}">
          <img class="first-slide" alt="slide {{#if 
                $first}}active{{/if}}">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>JAX 2015</h2>
                <hr/>
                <p>{{desc}}</p>
                </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="carousel-image">
                      <img src="{{film}}" alt="Slide Image" 
                               />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           {{/each}}
        </div>
                .....
    </div>
  </div>
```

I wanted to know if there were ways to bypass the limitation through external packages or simply a js function.

Comment: it seems that the first part went to text instead of code, anyway its the array and helper which I use in the template

Answer (score 1):

### 3rd party package

There is a package called raix:handlebar-helpers, which implements helpers such as $last, etc. See: https://atmospherejs.com/raix/handlebar-helpers

### Blaze built-in variable

Blaze has a built special variable `@index`, which can be used inside the body of `#each` to get the 0-based index of the currently rendered value in the sequence.

See http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each for more details.

This would however require further work to implement the `first` / `last` helpers using this.

Comment: You may add to your answer, that if only the first element is required it makes sense to implement it in favor of the package, while the package makes sense when more helpers like last and eq  are required.